# Custom arrow up/down Accordion Vertical Menu Foundation 6

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

How can i change in Foundation 6 for the Accordion Vertical Menu the standard arrow (up/down)  to a Custom-Icon Arrow up/down?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking in the Accordion's source code, you can change the `content` property of the arrow and override Foundation's default settings. this is the default property from [Foundation's Docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/accordion.html):

```
.accordion-title::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 1rem;
    margin-top: -0.5rem;
    content: '+';
}
```

So, change the `content` property to whatever you like - [Font Awesome](http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/), some [html entity](http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/04/named-html-entities-in-numeric-order/) or anything else:

```
.accordion-title::before {
    // Font Awesome implementation:
    content: "\f000";

    // HTML entity: 
    content:"\003e"; 
}
```

Happy Exploring :)

Comment: glad to help :) @robce

Answer (score 0):

To get it to work with Font Awesome you need to add in your CSS:

```
font-family: "Font Awesome";
```

Thereafter you can add extra parameters like:

```
font-style: normal;
font-size: 20px;
```